# how to convert windows forms browser control's document object to mshtml.IHTMLDocument2

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Trying to get this line to work

```
 mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = webBrowser1.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
```

but getting the error message

Error 10 Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' to 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Which I haven't come across before. I've done some searching and it seems many others have gotten that line to work? Any help / explanations greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2 currentDoc =
    (MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
```

I found the reference online at:
[HtmlDocument.DomDocument - at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.domdocument.aspx)

Comment: I have the same proble but I have no 'Document.DomDocument' property in MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2... any idea? Tnx